# Match a unique column to two separate columns

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have one column in google sheet with unique values. I then want to match this column to two separate columns. See google sheet below for an example. I want the output in column "B".

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10AOYlqsScoDUfcOaJd2opjjC_8zXSOP3_HBTOCCrb6U/edit#gid=0][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `maxifs`:

```
=maxifs($F$4:$H$14,$E$4:$G$14,A4)
```

[image]

A longer approach could be the following:

```
=max(vlookup(A4,$E$4:$F$14,2,false),vlookup(A4,$G$4:$H$14,2,false))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(F4:F14, H4:H14), "where Col1 is not null")
```

[image: 0]